# Why does the Happy Anniversary box come with two evil counters for every player?

Tags: dungeon-lords

The back of the box lists the four player-colored cubes as "evil counters". I don't see four more elsewhere. Is it just a mistake that the box comes with twice as many as needed? Or are they useful for some other purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same "Happy Anniversary" edition of Dungeon Lords and can only find one cube of each colour for the evil-o-meter.  So unless I suspect in your case its just a minor packing error and you have 4 extra cubes.